# How to make a callback after successful API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make an api call `useUserDetails`
after succussfully got the `tokenResponse` , but currently before the `tokenResponse`  useUserDetails is getting called. How to make a calback after succussfull call of `tokenResponse`

```
export default function UserDetails(): JSX.Element {
  const handShakeToken = useHandShakeToken(authCode);
  const tokenResponse = useMemo(() => {
    return handShakeToken?.data?.response;
  }, [handShakeToken]);

  // Below need to be called after I have received the token Response, but it is getting called intially
  const { data: customerDetails } = useUserDetails();

  useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("tokenStorageKey",tokenResponse?.accessToken || "");   
  }, [tokenResponse]);

  return (
    <div className="containerCss">
      <ListOfUsers />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Show the code for `useUserDetails`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the request inside the useEffect, where you have tokenResponse in your dependencies array. And you need to check for it to be truthy. Something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (tokenResponse) { // check for tokenResponse to ensure it's not falsy
      // I'm not sure where you'll be using this data, but you can extract it from here.
      const { data: customerDetails } = useUserDetails(); 
      sessionStorage.setItem("tokenStorageKey",tokenResponse?.accessToken || "");   
    }
  }, [tokenResponse]);
```

If you need to extract the data returned from the request, you can also do it by declaring it outside the if-block.

And if you need to make the request only once, when tokenResponse was first received, you can create a flag that will additionally satisfy the check. It depends on your task, there may be several ways to implement it :)